# How to reference a foreign key that just got inserted via auto-increment to two insert queries

Tags: php, mysql, sql, auto-increment, sql-insert

I have two tables for my forum-type system, it looks like this:

```
TBLTHREAD
* thread_id
* user_id
* date_posted
* thread_title

TBLPOST
* post_id
* thread_id (FK)
* user_id
* date_posted
* post_message
```

And as we all know, when you create a new thread in forums, you also make the first post. This is where I am having troubles with.

I have a form that looks like this:

```
    <form method="post" action="new_thread_result.php" target="_self">
    <table>

    <tr>
    <td>Title:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="title" required></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Message:</td>
    <td><textarea name="message" cols="30" rows="10" required></textarea></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><center><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></center></td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    </form>
```

and of course, the insertion in TBLTHREAD would look like this:

```
$query="INSERT INTO tblthread (user_id, thread_title, thread_status) VALUES ('$_SESSION[id_ni_user]','$_POST[title]','$status')";
$result=mysql_query($query,$db) or die (mysql_error($db));
```

Now my problem is, I just posted the thread I made, and since I am using auto-increment, I have no idea what thread_id it was assigned to. Basically, I am stuck at what to put in the **TBLPOST.thread_id** column.

Suggestions, anyone? Thank you in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

After the insert, you need to use LAST_INSERT_ID() to retrieve the value of an identity column.

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()
```